# React Native fetching items from database using Flatlist and listitem to display data

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist, listitem, react-native-elements

I am fetching data from my database and displaying it on my UI using flatlist and listitem. I am fetching the data on one screen, and then I am using navigation props to send that data to the next screen. Everything is working correctly but when I display the data using flatlist and listitem all the data is bunched together on one line. I have tried to use a line break in my php code from my backend and that doesn't work.

I have tried to use RegExp in javascript to separate the data and that doesn't work. I feel like I am missing something so small, I just can't put my finger on it.

Here is my fetch method that grabs the data from my backend and sends it to the next screen.

```js
_openTable = (item) => {
        fetch('URL', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({tablenumber: item}),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
        })
            .then((response) => response.text())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: responseJson,
                });
                console.log(responseJson)
                alert(responseJson)
                this.props.navigation.navigate('ViewParty', {
                    party: responseJson,
                    otherParam: '101',
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
    GetGridViewItem(uname) {
        Alert.alert(uname);
    }
```

Here is my code for getting the data from the last screen and displaying it through Flatlist and Listitem.

```js
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataSource: [],
        }
    }

    render() {

        const  { navigation } = this.props;
        const cust = navigation.getParam('party', 'No-User');
        const other_param = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'No-User');

        const cust1 = JSON.stringify(cust);
        const cust2 = cust1.replace(/[\])}[{(]/g, '');
        const cust3 = cust2.replace(/[""]/g, '');
        const cust4 = cust3.replace(/[,]/g, '');
        const cust5 = cust4.replace(/[\\]/g, '');

        let data = this.state.dataSource;
        data.push([cust5]);

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MenuButtonWS navigation={this.props.navigation} />
                <FlatList
                    data={data}
                    extraData={this.state}
                    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                    //numColumns={numColumns}
                    renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                        <ListItem
                        titleStyle={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                        title={`${item}`}
                        bottomDivider
                        chevron
                        />
                    )}
                />
            </View>
```

When I console.log the data this is an example of what I will get..["sam123","beth345"]. It will display in my listitem like this. All on one line....  sam123beth345. Please help.

Comment: `.then((response) => response.text())` should be `.then((response) => response.json())` maybe

Comment: thank you so much for replying @skorp. I have tried both .text() and .json() and they both give me the same outcome. I have used the same way to fetch data from my database in other parts of my code and it works fine. I just don't understand it.

Comment: It seems like the data is being converted into one big string instead of an array. What format is the data returned to you? Why do you need to use regex to convert to array? Maybe you could post the raw data as it's returned to you and the full console.log of your formatted array.

Comment: if i run all your cust*.replaces the last output of cust5 is : sam123beth345

remove them it should work.

`JSON.stringify(cust);` is needed don't remove that

why are this replace's needed?

Comment: @RossHochwert thank you so much for replying. Yes it's being displayed as one big string. It's being returned as an array. I am using regexp to remove the brackets and the quotation marks. When I console.log it I get ["sam123","beth345"]. I am just trying to get the user names to fit into the listitem.

Comment: @skorp when I remove them and just leave JSON.stringify I get ["sam123","beth345"] inside of one of the listitem rows. I just need for sam123 to be in one row and beth345 to be in another row.

Comment: If it's being returned as an array, you shouldn't need to do any regex. Can you post what the return data is (e.g., `cust`) is? If that's a string, `cust.split(", ")` should convert it to an array for you.

Comment: @RossHochwert when I return it and have it console.log it comes back as ["sam123","beth345"]. When I don't use any regexp and just use the JSON.stringify(cust). which will be cust1.split(", ") I get...                                                        . "[\"sam123\",                                                                                                                  .  \"beth345\"]". The way I have it here is the way that it is displaying, right underneath. It's not in two different rows, it's in the same row but the row is getting bigger.

Comment: are you pushing cust1 to data?  is this also removed `data.push([cust1]);` the flatlist should handle the array correctly normally, is your code looking like this in last version ` <FlatList
                    data={cust1}.....` ??
if not can you update your question with the latest version of your code pls.

Comment: @skorp when I push cust1 to data ....data.push([cust1]). I get the same output but instead of it all being in one row. I get the response vertical, and every row has a letter in it. So row one will have [ in it, and row two will have ", and row three will have s, and so on and so on.

Comment: If the data comes back in an array already, why not just push `data.push(cust)`. When you do `data.push([cust])` you create a nested array which FlatList may reading as one element.

Comment: I removed the brackets like you said and I just have it as data.push(cust). I also changed {`${item}`} to {item} because no data would so if I didn't. So now I am just getting this "[\"sam123\","\beth345\"]".

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

```
render() {
    const  { navigation } = this.props;
    const cust = navigation.getParam('party', 'No-User');
    const other_param = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'No-User');

    const cust1 = JSON.stringify(cust);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MenuButtonWS navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            <FlatList
                data={cust1}
                extraData={this.state}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                //numColumns={numColumns}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <ListItem
                    titleStyle={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                    title={item}
                    bottomDivider
                    chevron
                    />
                )}
            />
        </View>
```

if `const cust1 = JSON.stringify(cust);` looks like this: ["sam123","beth345"] then this should work.

see a working example here: [snack example](https://snack.expo.io/@skorp/flatlist-array-usage)
if its not working, console.log data, cust && cust1

**update**

```
render() {
    const  { navigation } = this.props;
    const cust = navigation.getParam('party', 'No-User');
    const other_param = navigation.getParam('otherParam', 'No-User');

    data = [...cust]
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <MenuButtonWS navigation={this.props.navigation} />
            <FlatList
                data={data}
                extraData={this.state}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
                //numColumns={numColumns}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => (
                    <ListItem
                    titleStyle={{ color: 'black', fontWeight: 'bold'}}
                    title={item}
                    bottomDivider
                    chevron
                    />
                )}
            />
        </View>
```

Comment: I really appreciate you helping me out with this. Ok so I did change my code to match what you have above and I am still getting the same thing "[\"sam123\","\beth345\"]". When I look at your snack example it is working but you don't have the listitem inside of the flatlist.

Comment: i don't think the listitem is the problem, i think your problem is that your datasource is not a valid array. i updated the example with listitem. show us how your cust variable looks like after this line`const cust = navigation.getParam('party', 'No-User');` https://snack.expo.io/@skorp/flatlist-array-usage

Comment: so when i navigate to the next screen and I console.log cust I get this ["sam123","beth345"]. So it is an array. I have my datasource in my constructor(props). I looked at you snack and what you have there I have in my code, but its not working like how you have it.

Comment: so this first one is my response data that I am getting back after fetching from database.["mh036","lh035","padams11","ahall09"]...........
this one here is after i send it over through navigation props and I console.log cust after i do this.state.dataSource.push(cust); ["[\"mh036\",\"lh035\",\"padams11\",\"ahall09\"]"]

Comment: If i change cust to cust1 which does JSON.stringify(cust); i get ...........................................["\"[\\\"mh036\\\",\\\"lh035\\\",\\\"padams11\\\",\\\"ahall09\\\"]\""] when i console.log cust1

Comment: ok i understand, thats what i try to say, cust is an array so use it directly, if you want to add it to your data variable then use `data = [...cust]` NO JSON.stringify NO data.push, when you push, you are adding your array(cust)  into another array(data), so the data[0] will contain your array from cust. output of data will look like this:
`[ 0: ["mh036","lh035","padams11","ahall09"]]` and thats wrong, if its not working please post your last version of code somewhere so we can check.

Comment: Ok so i tried what you said and did data = [...cust] and it gives me ["[", "\"", "l", "j", "n", "0", "3", "9", "\"", ",", "\"", "d", "o", "k", "o", "n", "m", "a", "h", "3", "9", "\"", ",", "\"", "p", "h", "a", "l", "l", "7", "7", "7", "\"", "]"]. I have added my code here.... https://github.com/jca-38/customerQJS. Please look at TableJS first that's the code that sends the info over to ViewpartyJS.

Comment: please check and control your datasource, i added a new snack with your error cases.i hope it will help you to find the error: https://snack.expo.io/@skorp/66daf4

Comment: ok thank you so much for your help. I will find the error and solve this problem.

Comment: I figure it out!!!! I figured out that I was creating a nested array with the const data = [cust]. I took off the [] and instead of cust1 = JSON.stringify I did cust1 = JSON.parse(cust) and it works now!!!! Thank you for your help!!